# How can I combine arrays of time slots while tracking a linked ID in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm creating a scheduling system for a grooming salon. What needs to happen is when a client is scheduling their pet, the system only gives available times. Once the client selects an available time, if there is more than one groomer available, the system needs to assign the pet to the groomer with the highest seniority.

I currently have a nested array with each groomer's information, and an array of 
 time slots they have available.

Here is an example of the array:

```
timeslots (
    0 => array (
        groomer => array (
            ID => 0,
            Seniority => 5,
            ...
        ),
        slots => array (
            0 => array (
                start => 200,
                end => 450,
                length => 250
            ),
            1 => array (
                start => 500,
                end => 600,
                length => 100
            )
        )
    ),
    1 => array (...),
    2 => array (...)
)
```

I need to combine all of the slots into a single array in order to fill a  box. However, any overlapping timeslots would need to be merged, and I still need a way to track which groomer is the most senior for a given timeslot that is selected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a suggestion than an answer, but I think using classes will help you find the answer to your own problem.

```
class Groomer {
  constructor(id, seniority) {
    this.id = id,
    this.seniority = seniority,
    this.timeslots => {
      someFunctionThatGetsTimeslots();
    }
  }
}
```